# Are there results from gauge theory known or conjectured to distinguish smooth from PL manifolds?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, gauge-theory

My question begins with a caveat: I sometimes spend time with topologists, but do not consider myself to be one.  In particular, my apologies for any errors in what I say below — corrections are encouraged.

My impression is that manifold topologists like to consider three main categories of (finite-dimensional, paracompact, Hausdorff) manifolds, which I will call $\mathcal C^0$, $\mathrm{PL}$, and $\mathcal C^\infty$, corresponding to manifolds whose atlases have transition functions that are, respectively, homeomorphisms, piecewise-affine transformations, and diffeomorphisms.  The latter two categories obvious map faithfully into the first, and a theorem of Whitehead says that every $\mathcal C^\infty$ manifold admits a unique PL structure.

These categories are not equivalent in any reasonable sense.  The generalized Poincare conjecture is true in $\mathcal C^0$, true (except possibly in dimension $4$) in $\mathrm{PL}$, and false in many dimensions including $7$ in $\mathcal C^\infty$.  $\mathcal C^0$ is the realm of surgery and h-cobordism.  In $\mathcal C^\infty$, and in particular in $4$ dimensions, there is a powerful tool called "gauge theory", which provides the main technology used to prove examples of homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic manifolds.

By definition, *gauge theory* is that part of PDE that studies connections on principal $G$-bundles for Lie groups $G$.  The most important gauge theories for distinguishing between the $\mathcal C^\infty$ and $\mathcal C^0$ worlds are Donaldson Theory (which studies the moduli space of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ connections with self-dual curvature) and the conjecturally equivalent Seiberg–Witten Theory (which studies an abelian gauge field along with a matter field, and which I understand less well).  Another important gauge theory that I understand much better is (three-dimensional) Chern–Simons Theory, whose PDE picks out the moduli space of flat $G$ connections; for example, counting with sign the flat $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ connections on a 3-manifold is supposed to correspond to the Casson invariant.

My impression, furthermore, has been that the categories $\mathcal C^\infty$ and $\mathrm{PL}$ are in fact quite close.  There are more objects in the latter, certainly, but in fact many of the results separating $\mathcal C^0$ from $\mathcal C^\infty$ in fact separate $\mathcal C^0$ from $\mathrm{PL}$.  A side version of my question is to understand in better detail the distance between $\mathcal C^\infty$ and $\mathrm{PL}$.  But my main question is whether the technology of *gauge theory* (possibly broadly defined) can be used to separate them.  A priori, the whole theory of PDE is based on smooth structures, so it would not be unreasonable, but I am not aware of examples.

> Are there gauge-theoretic invariants of smooth manifolds that distinguish nondiffeomorphic but $\mathrm{PL}$-isomorphic manifolds?

Of course, a simple answer would be something like "For any $X,Y \in \mathcal C^\infty$, the inclusion $\mathcal C^\infty \hookrightarrow \mathrm{PL}$ induces a homotopy equivalence of mapping spaces $\mathcal C^\infty(X,Y) \to \mathrm{PL}(X,Y)$."  This would explain the impression I have that $\mathcal C^\infty$ and $\mathrm{PL}$ are close — if it is true, it is not something I recall having been told.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, it follows from the work of Kirby and Siebenmann that in dimensions $\le 6$ PL and DIFF categories are equivalent. In particular, if you are working in dimension 4 (where gauge-theoretic invariants are mostly used) then the answer to your your question is negative. Starting in dimension 7, there are smooth manifolds which are PL-equivalent but not diffeomorphic. Milnor's exotic 7-spheres are the first examples of such manifolds. The smooth structures on Milnor's spheres are distinguished via index and 1st Pontryagin class. Whether you consider such invariants gauge-theoretic or not, depends on how broadly you interpret gauge theory. For instance, characteristic classes of smooth manifolds can be defined via differential forms, i.e., Chern-Weil theory, or as indices of some elliptic operators. Does this qualify as gauge theory? (You can lift forms from, say, tangent bundle to the principal bundle- frame bundle, if you so desire.) The point of usage of gauge theory in dimension 4 is that the "traditional" topological invariants turned out to be insufficient, so one considers spaces of connections satisfying some differential equation (like self-duality) and uses such spaces to derive some smooth invariants of 4-manifolds. As far as I know, nobody used this viewpoint in higher (i.e., at least 7) dimensions, since there was no need for it.

Answer (score 6):

In *Foundational Essays on Topological Manifolds, Smoothings, and Triangulations*, Kirby and Seibenmann show homotopy equivalence of the Kan complexes $\mathrm{Man}^m_{sm}$ and $\mathrm{Man}^m_{PL}$ for $m\leq 3$, , that can be thought of as classifying spaces of smooth and of PL $m$-manifolds correspondingly (an earlier version of this answer stated this for all $m$, which is false). Jacob Lurie wrote [a very nice set of lecture notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/937.html) on just this topic. Perhaps this is the statement you want? Restricted to one skeletons, it gives homotopy equivalence of mapping spaces for low dimensions- but the full statement tells you much more, and it provides a precise and intuitively satisfying sense in which smooth and PL categories are `close' for low dimensions. In higher dimensions, PL manifolds can be smoothed in dimension $\leq 7$, essentially uniquely in dimension $\leq 6$.

The definitions of the `classifying spaces' are roughly as follows. For a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and for a smooth $m$-manifold $M$, the simplicial set $\mathrm{Emb}^m_{sm}(M,V)$ is defined to have $n$-simplices as embeddings $M\times\Delta^n\rightarrow V\times\Delta^n$ which commute with the projection to $n$. Now let $\mathrm{Sub}^m_{sm}(V)$ denote the simplicial set of *submanifolds* of $V$, whose $n$-simplices are given as smooth submanifolds $X\subseteq V\times\Delta^n$ such that the projection $X\rightarrow \Delta^n$ is a smooth fibre bundle of relative dimension $n$. If $V$ is infinite dimensional, we define $\mathrm{Sub}_{sm}(V)$ as the direct limit of  $\mathrm{Sub}_{sm}(V_0)$ as $V_0$ ranges over all finite dimensional subspaces of $V$. The parallel definitions in the PL case define $\mathrm{Sub}_{PL}(V)$. For a fixed infinite dimensional vector space $V$, the Kan complexes $\mathrm{Man}^m_{sm}$ and $\mathrm{Man}^m_{PL}$ are defined as $\mathrm{Sub}^m_{sm}(V)$ and $\mathrm{Sub}^m_{PL}(V)$ correspondingly.

Comment: (I fixed a formatting conflict.)

Comment: Kirby and Siebenmann show no such thing, as the statement claimed is false. The $E_8$ PL-manifold in any dimension $4k \geq 8$ (obtained by forming the $E_8$-plumbing and coning off the boundary, which is a PL sphere) is not smoothable, so any reasonable map $Man_{sm}^m \to Man_{PL}^m$ is not even surjective on path-components, never mind a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @Oscar: corrected to make the statement only for $m\leq 3$. Sorry about that.